# if record exists display error message in viewbag in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

here i have a scenario in which i want to check if record already exists then display error message on view. if record not exists then render partial view , and if record not exists  means add record successfully render partial view. 
in viewbag.i tried but failed ,can any one help.
thank you in advance 
**Controller Action Method**

```
public ActionResult ManageRole(TBL_ADMIN_ROLE role)
        {
            if (dbcontext.TBL_ADMIN_ROLE.Any(role1 => role1.RoleName.Equals(role.RoleName) && role1.IsDeleted == 0))
            {

                ViewBag.ExistsRecord = "Record Already Exists";
            }
            if (TryUpdateModel(role))
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    role.IsDeleted = 0;
                    role.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    dbcontext.TBL_ADMIN_ROLE.Add(role);
                    role.CreatedByID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
                    dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                    dbcontext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    List<TBL_ADMIN_ROLE> roleList = dbcontext.TBL_ADMIN_ROLE.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == 0).ToList();
                    return PartialView("_ManageRoleList", roleList);
                }
            }
            return View(role);

        }
```

**View**

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ManageRole", "Security", null, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "DisplayRoleGrid",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnSuccess = "oNsuccess"
    }))
    {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div id="divmessage">
            <label id="successmessage"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
               @ViewBag.ExistsRecord
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4">


            @(Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("RoleName")
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Role Name", required = "required", validationmessage = "Enter {0}", data_required_msg = "Enter Role Name" }))

        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Unclear what your trying to do. Your controller method has a pointless `if (TryUpdateModel(role))` - its already been updated/bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`. All your doing is adding a `ViewBag` message and then saving it anyway,even if it does exist. You main view has `@ViewBag.ExistsRecord` but that would need to be in the partial, because that's where it exists

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can i resolve now ? i mean what to do now ?

Comment: Its not even clear what your really want to do and so much of your code makes no sense. For a start you should decorate your `RoleName` property with `[Required]` (remove the `data_required_msg = "Enter Role Name"` and then use a `RemoteAttribute` to check if the role exists - [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx) and include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoleName)` in your view.

Comment: And what is the `IsDeleted` property for? Surely if its exists and is marked as deleted, you then mark it as not deleted rather than adding another duplicate? And rather than updating the whole collection, you should consider just add a new row to table of roles in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`if (dbcontext.TBL_ADMIN_ROLE.Any(role1 => role1.RoleName.Equals(role.RoleName) && role1.IsDeleted == 0))
    {
    ViewBag.ExistsRecord = "Record Already Exists";
Return View(Role);
     }`

Not sure what you are trying to do. You don't have to do this with Viewbag to return an error. You can use AddModelError for this